# SED - Replace First Occurence of Number in Middle of String

Tags: regex, sed

I just started with regex and sed, and I am having an issue with the following:

```
echo "abc2def3ghi" | sed 's/^\(.*\)[0-9]\(.*\)$/"&" \1\2/i'
```

I am looking to remove the first digit (2 in this case, but can by any single digit), but I get the following as a result:

```
"abc2def3ghi" abc2defghi
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed 's/[0-9]//1' file.txt
```

The number `1` in `s///1` stands for Nth occurence

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answered, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` has no reluctant/non-greedy quantifier, so you have to match zero or more non-digits specifically:

```
^\([^0-9]*\)[0-9]\(.*\)$
```

Comment: Thanks for elucidating in the context of my original thought process.  Much obliged.